# C#, a Simple issue with server/client chatting

Tags: c#

I have 2 projects in C#, one is a a server, and one is a client. Using a background worker, they chat asynchronously. The server is sending messages, and the client is getting them and showing them just fine, but if I send a message from client to server, the first time it works fine, then it doesn't send from the client any more. After that, trying to send from server to client still works fine, but client will only send that first message. Can anyone help me figure why?

EDIT:
This GIF shows exactly whats happening: https://gyazo.com/ce0803519702d3080ddc57d0ef45ae0c

Server:

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Windows.Forms;
    using System.Net;
    using System.Net.Sockets;
    using System.IO;

    namespace SeaboltServerHw5
    {
public partial class Server : Form
{
    String str;
    TcpListener listen = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 18888);
    Boolean connected = false;
    StreamReader inn;
    StreamWriter outt;
    Socket sock; 
    NetworkStream stream;
    public Server()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        serverRun.RunWorkerAsync();      
    }

    private void StartServer()
    {
        listen.Start();
        sock = listen.AcceptSocket();
        connected = true;
        stream = new NetworkStream(sock);
        inn = new StreamReader(stream);
        outt = new StreamWriter(stream);
        outt.AutoFlush = true;
    }

    private void serverRun_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        StartServer();
        if (connected == true)
        {
            str = inn.ReadLine();
        }
        else
            return;
    }

    private void serverRun_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        //lblConnect.Text = "Client Connected.";
        rtbData.AppendText("From Client: " + str + "\n");
        serverRun.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    private void tbEnter_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
        {
            String temp = tbEnter.Text;
            outt.WriteLine(temp);
            rtbData.AppendText("From Server: " + temp + "\n");
            tbEnter.Text = "";
        }
        else
            return;
    }


}
  }
```

Client:

```
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Windows.Forms;
    using System.Net;
    using System.Net.Sockets;
    using System.IO;

   namespace SeaboltClientHW5
   {
public partial class Client : Form
{
    String str;
    Boolean connected = false;
    TcpClient client = new TcpClient();
    NetworkStream stream;
    StreamReader inn;
    StreamWriter outt;
    public Client()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        client.Connect("127.0.0.1", 18888);
        bgWork.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    public void startClient()
    {

        connected = true;
        stream = client.GetStream();
        inn = new StreamReader(stream);
        outt = new StreamWriter(stream);
        outt.AutoFlush = true;
    }

    private void bgWork_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        startClient();
        if (connected == true)
        {
            str = inn.ReadLine();
        }
        else
            return;
    }

    private void bgWork_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        rtbData.AppendText("From Server: " + str + "\n");
        bgWork.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    private void tbEnter_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
        {
            String temp = tbEnter.Text;
            outt.WriteLine(temp);
            rtbData.AppendText("From Client: " + temp + "\n");
            tbEnter.Text = "";
        }
        else
            return;
    }


 }
  }
```

Comment: Where are your `bgWork` and `serverRun` variables created? What do the `RunWorkerAsync()` methods do? Have you tried debugging? Does the event on the server get called?

Comment: @krillgar those are background workers.  Those are basic events for background workers.

Comment: Are they declared in `Program.cs`? Did you put a breakpoint in the listener even on the server window?

Comment: @krillgar I added them using the toolbox on visual studio.  Everything is working well but for some reason Server is not getting any more messages after it gets the 1st.

Comment: Gotcha. So they're probably created in the code behind partial class. Sorry about that!

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that `listen.AcceptSocket()` (which is waiting for **new** incomming connection) is not called just once, but after each message. For the first time, it succeeds as soon as *Client* is started and server accepts first message. But for the second time it waits indefinitelly (until new Client is started) and server gets stucked.

This is probably why you have there `connected` variable - but as it is now, it is useless, because after `StartServer()` is called, condition `if (connected == true)` will always be true. To ensure that `listen.AcceptSocket()` will be called just for the first time, rewrite server's `serverRun_DoWork` as this:

```
private void serverRun_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    if (!connected)
        StartServer();

    str = inn.ReadLine();
}
```

Similar change should be done for client too, but unlike server, it is not so much problem because client code calls `client.GetStream()`, which if called repeatedly, returns immediately existing network stream, so although it is superfluous to call `client.GetStream()` after each message, it is basicaly harmless.

```
private void bgWork_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    if (!connected)
        startClient();

    str = inn.ReadLine();
}
```